# How to deal with NaN values in R?

Tags: r, nan, na, missing-data

I'm testing for random intercepts as a preparation for growth curve modeling.

Therefore, I've first created a wide subset and then converted it to a Long data set.

Calculating my `ModelM1 <- gls(ent_act~1, data=school_l)` with the long data set, I get an error message as I have missing values. In my long subset these values are stated as NaN.

When applying `temp<-na.omit(school_l$ent_act)`, I can calculate ModelM1. But, when calculating ModelM2 `ModelM2 <- lme(temp~1, random=~1|ID, data=school_l)`, then I get the error message of my variables being of unqueal lengths.

How can I deal with those missing values? 
Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Pleaseread [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and then edit your question to provide a simple, self-contained example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you might get success with would be to make a temp dataframe where your remove entire lines indexed by negation of the missing condition: `!is.na(school_1$ent_act)`

```
temp<-school_l[ !is.na(school_l$ent_act), ]
```

Then re-run the `lme` call. There should now be no mismatch of variable lengths.

```
ModelM2 <- lme(ent_act  ~1, random= ~1|ID, data=school_l)
```

Note that using `school_l` is going to be potentially confusing because it looks so much like `school_1` when viewed in Times font.

Comment: Thank you! I think that worked. However, I somehow get "wrong" results as I get the same results for my model 1 and 2 which is not true looking at the data.. Also the intercept predicted by model 1 is far from my data. Does anyone see a mistake in my code?

Comment: ### Test for random intercept

```temp<-!is.na(school_l$ent_act) ``` 

```ModelM1 <- gls(temp~1, data=school_l) ```

```summary(ModelM1) ``` # average ent_act across all people and all time points: 0.6509222, p-value = 0
```logLik(ModelM1)``` # fit statistic: the closer to 0 the better (the less error you are making in the prediction) --> -1510.926
```deviance1 <- logLik(ModelM1)*-2``` # Deviance

Comment: # random coefficient model
```ModelM2 <- lme(temp~1, random=~1|ID, data=school_l) ```
```summary(ModelM2) ```
```logLik(ModelM2) ``` # -1510.926 (same as for model 1)
```deviance2 <- logLik(ModelM2)*-2```

```deviance1 - deviance2``` # difference in deviance: -3.159585e-09 (almost 0)
```anova(ModelM1, ModelM2) ``` # p-value = 1, absolutely not significant.

Comment: Do _not_ use comments to amend or modify questions. I think it might require a new question since this one was how to avoid unequal variable lengths and now (with this issue apparently solved) you are then having different problems with model fitting.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Sorry for that. Thank you!